# WebMvcConfiguration: WebMvcConfigurationSupport.setServletContext(@Nullable ServletContext servletContext)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have 2 spring boot applications.
One is working fine but for the second one I have the following error when starting the application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:591)
```

When I debug, the following method is called in first application but not in the second one:

```
WebMvcConfigurationSupport.setServletContext(@Nullable ServletContext servletContext)
```

I saw in Spring that it is set by a call to `ServletContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)`. The `ServletContextAwareProcessor` is initialized with a `servletContext` (not null) for the first application but the `servletContext` is null for the second application.

I do not understand why because all the configuration (WebMvcConfiguration, SecurityConfiguration, SwaggerConfiguration...) seems to be the same. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: This happens when something causes the bean that extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` to be created earlier then expected, and before the `ServletContext` is available. If you can share a minimal, reproducible example it should be possible to determine the cause of the early initialization.

Comment: Yes indeed, a bean (`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in my case) declared in WebMvcConfiguration was the cause of this behaviour. I detected it in debug by adding a breakpoint for each bean. This bean was not necessary in the second application so I deleted it and it works fine now. Thank you for the lead you gave me.